# US freight commodity flows by county or BEA

Tags: data-request, transportation

I am looking for data on freight commodity flows in US by county or BEA area for a two digit STCC code. The information that I need is how many tons or loads of freight of a given commodity was transported between a given origin-destination pair.

The best I could find so far was Commodity Flow Survey, but they only have data for around 80 metropolitan areas and everything else is aggregated to "rest of the state".